# How to add more than one text view in firebase realtime database from android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a cart fragment and I want that when someone clicks the checkout button he should be redirected to checkout activity and his products should go to the firebase Realtime database. It is working fine but in the database only one product is shown. But I want all products should be shown. Any help will be Appreciated.

**CartFagment.java**

```
package com.example.shoppingcart.views;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;



import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.shoppingcart.R;
import com.example.shoppingcart.adapters.CartListAdapter;
import com.example.shoppingcart.cartholder;
import com.example.shoppingcart.databinding.FragmentCartBinding;
import com.example.shoppingcart.models.CartItem;
import com.example.shoppingcart.repositories.CartRepo;
import com.example.shoppingcart.viewmodels.ShopViewModel;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class CartFragment extends Fragment implements CartListAdapter.CartInterface {

    private static final String TAG = "CartFragment";
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    public TextView productprice;
    public TextView productname;
    public Spinner productquantity;
    Spinner spinner;
    int quantity;
    ShopViewModel shopViewModel;
    FragmentCartBinding fragmentCartBinding;
    NavController navController;
    Button button;





    private void finishActivity() {
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }

    public CartFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         fragmentCartBinding = FragmentCartBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        return fragmentCartBinding.getRoot();



    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);

        final CartListAdapter cartListAdapter = new CartListAdapter(this);
        fragmentCartBinding.cartRecyclerView.setAdapter(cartListAdapter);
        fragmentCartBinding.cartRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(requireContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

        shopViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ShopViewModel.class);
        shopViewModel.getCart().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<CartItem>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<CartItem> cartItems) {
                cartListAdapter.submitList(cartItems);
                fragmentCartBinding.placeOrderButton.setEnabled(cartItems.size() > 0);
            }
        });

        shopViewModel.getTotalPrice().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Double>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Double aDouble) {
                fragmentCartBinding.orderTotalTextView.setText("Total: PKR " + aDouble.toString());
                String price=aDouble.toString().trim();
            }
        });

        button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.placeOrderButton);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                confirm();

            }
        });
    }

    public void confirm() {
        productprice = getView().findViewById(R.id.productTotalPriceTextView);
        productname=getView().findViewById(R.id.productNameTextView);

        final String saveCurrentDate, saveCurrentTime;

        Calendar calForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
        saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calForDate.getTime());

        SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
        saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(calForDate.getTime());



        spinner=getView().findViewById(R.id.quantitySpinner);

        String productPrice =productprice.getText().toString();
        String productN=productname.getText().toString();
        String productq= CartItem.getSelectedSpinnerValue(spinner,quantity);

        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        String randomUUIDString = uuid.toString().trim();

        cartholder op = new cartholder(productPrice,productq,productN, saveCurrentDate, saveCurrentTime);

        FirebaseDatabase dab = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference note = dab.getReference("Products");

        note.child(randomUUIDString).child(productN).setValue(op);


        Intent intent = new Intent(CartFragment.this.getActivity(), CheckoutActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finishActivity();
    }


    @Override
    public void deleteItem(CartItem cartItem) {
        shopViewModel.removeItemFromCart(cartItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void changeQuantity(CartItem cartItem, int quantity) {
        shopViewModel.changeQuantity(cartItem, quantity);
    }



    }
```

**fragment_cart.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".views.CartFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cartRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/cart_row"
            tools:itemCount="2"
            />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orderTotalTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="Total: PKR 26"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/placeOrderButton"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="Proceed To Checkout"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I want all products to show but only one product is showing in database

Comment: And that's wrong? What isn't working the way you want?

Comment: I want all products to show so I know what they want I cannot just ship one product when they ordered 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
cartholder op = new cartholder(productPrice,productq,productN, saveCurrentDate, saveCurrentTime);

..

note.child(randomUUIDString).child(productN).setValue(op);
```

It's because you are uploading only one product your CartHolder object contains only one product.

```
CartHolder op = new CartHolder(cartItems, saveCurrentDate, saveCurrentTime);
note.child(randonUUIDString).set(op);
```

Create extra class for Product to store all necessary details of product and change CartHolder class to take List

If you want to use the same approach you must use a loop to store all products one by one, but I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

As the first answered said ***you are just adding lots of item values into one child***. ***If you want your code to add all of user's items which are in his cart, You should make it to add them in different child***. Here is my example.

```
    FirebaseDatabase dab = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference note = dab.getReference("Products");

    note.child(randomUUIDString).child(yourProductName).setValue(op);
```

In this case, ***you need to set 'yourProductName' different***. I mean ***you should not use the name that has been used before***.

***If you want to make lists of products, create new class and make new list and add them into the list***. Next, just ***use 'for' to loop your code and add all the products into your database***. Hope this is helpful :)